# How to do multiple insert as well update by using dapper .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, orm, dapper

How to do multiple insert (50000 record) as well update using dapper .net ?

1. Is it possible to use `SqlBulkCopy` to achieve this? If yes then how?
2. Is there any best way to implement multiple hierarchical insert or update using Dapper.net?

Technologies : C#, SQL Server 2012, Dapper.net

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want to insert: SqlBulkCopy should be fine; if you want an "upsert", I suggest table-valued-parameters (which dapper supports) and the `merge` t-sql operation
2. Dapper just simplifies ado.net; if you think of a way to do it in ado.net, dapper can probably make it easier for you; however, it sounds like *multiple* TVPs might suffice

Comment: is it possible for you to share some code example for sqlbulkcopy with dapper .net  for multiple insert

Comment: @RakeshGaur you don't need dapper to do `SqlBulkCopy`; you just *use `SqlBulkCopy`*. However, note that FastMember (a separate library) has some tools to make this handy, especially when the input source is a set of objects - it allows `IEnumerable<T>` to be treated as a streaming `IDataReader`, which is what `SqlBulkCopy` consumes

Answer (score 0):

If you are mean to OK and able to segregate insert and update entities separately then I would suggest to use Dapper.Contrib library provided by Dapper.Net guys themselves. It is available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/). It has worked very efficiently for my project.

Here is the link to their [Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) project page.